# Appharbor and Amazon SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, appharbor

Do applications hosted on Appharbor qualify for the Amazon SES 62,000 messages per month at the free tier?

"If you are an Amazon EC2 user, you can start sending with Amazon SES for free. You can send 62,000 messages per month to any recipient when you call Amazon SES from an Amazon EC2 instance directly or through AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Additionally, you can also receive 1,000 messages per month for free on Amazon SES. Many applications are able to operate entirely within this free tier limit, and it does not expire after a year."

https://aws.amazon.com/ses/pricing/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes is the answer to this question.